# PowerShell Script to Validate/compare Folder and files of Two servers

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the number of files inside folders and number of folders along with total size. To a certain extent I have achieved that goal but when I am trying it for checking millions of folders/files and their size may be around 1 TB its getting stuck might be getting into infinite lope.

Also I want to compare the two location size and number of files/folder and get output as bollen value. – `true` if the size and numbers match, `false` if they don’t.

Below script is what I tried. Can some one help me with the requirement.

```
$hostnames = Get-Content C:\server.txt
$directory = "D$\logs"

foreach ($hostname in $hostnames){

    $Folderitems = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$hostname\$directory" -Directory -Recurse -Force).Count  
    $FileItems = Get-ChildItem -path "\\$hostname\$directory" -recurse
    $Measurement = $FileItems | Measure-Object -property length -sum
    $colitems = $FileItems | measure-Object -property length -sum
    "$hostname,$directory;{0:N2}" -f ($colitems.sum / 1024MB) + "GB;" + $Measurement.count + " files;" + $items +"Folders;" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A performance improvement would be to invoke the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet only once and use it to filter the Folders using the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet:

```
$FileItems = Get-ChildItem -path "\\$hostname\$directory" -recurse
$Folderitems = $FileItems | Where-Object PsIsContainer
```

You also calculate the length twice, remove one of these:

```
$Measurement = $FileItems | Measure-Object -property length -sum
$colitems = $FileItems | measure-Object -property length -sum
```

> Also i want to compare the two location size and number of
>   files/folder and get output as bollen value.

Which two locations you want to compare? You are iterating over a list of hostnames and don't store any values...

**Edit to your comment:**

> Regarding the comparison part i want to compare the size and number of
>   files from server1 to server2 for location d$\website. Its just like
>   same we do right click on folder and see the files and size.

Currently, you are retrieving the items for `D$\logs`, not `D$\website` you probably have to change this?!. To compare the results, you have to store them first. I would recommend an `array` of `PSCustomObjects`. The structure looks like this (sample output):

```
Server           Sum Count
------           --- -----
YourServer1 88575206   386
YourServer2 88575206   386
```

And here the script:

```
foreach ($hostname in $hostnames){

    $FileItems = Get-ChildItem -path "\\$hostname\$directory" -recurse

    $Folderitems = $FileItems | Where-Object PsIsContainer
    $Measurement = $FileItems | Measure-Object -property length -sum

    $serverFileMeasurements += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = $hostname
        Sum = $Measurement.Sum
        Count = $Measurement.Count
    }
}

# assuming there are only two servers:
if ($serverFileMeasurements[0].Count -eq $serverFileMeasurements[1].Count -and 
    $serverFileMeasurements[0].Sum -eq $serverFileMeasurements[1].Sum)
{
    Write-Host $true
}
else
{
    Write-Host $false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for above suggestion i will try and let you know. Regarding the comparison part i want to compare the size and number of files from server1 to server2 for location d$\website. Its just like same we do right click on folder and see the files and size.

Comment: Thanks but seems error:- Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain 
a method named 'op_Addition'. Also since one of my folder is on NAS drive which is quite huge so script is getting stuck at that position.

Comment: You probably adopt the code because this one runs without exception?